# Getting "Internal Server Error" in my node.js app using passport.js facebook strategy

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, passport.js, facebook-login

In my Node app I am using Passport.js Facebook Strategy. I have successfully deplayed my app on heroku and also have made my app public. But only if I login it works. If someone else logs in it promts Internal Server Error.
To check, I checked my mlab  database but no data of the logged in user displays.

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const session = require('express-session');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var path = require("path");

// var path = require("path");

//jade
// const jade = require('jade');

//Load Models
require('./models/User');
require('./models/Story');

//Passport config
require('./config/passport')(passport);

//Load Routes
const index = require('./routes/index');
const auth = require('./routes/auth');
const stories = require('./routes/stories');

//Load Keys
const keys = require('./config/keys');

//handlebars helpers
const {
  truncate,
  stripTags,
  formatDate,
  select,
  editIcon
} = require('./helpers/hbs');

//Load Global Promise
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

//Mongoose Connect
mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI,{
  useMongoClient: true,
})
.then(()=>console.log('MongoDB Connected............'))
.catch(err => console.log(err))

const app = express();

// body-parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
  helpers: {
    truncate: truncate,
    stripTags: stripTags,
    formatDate: formatDate,
    select: select,
    editIcon: editIcon
  },
  defaultLayout: 'main'
}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));


// app.set('view engine', 'jade');

//Session n cookieParser Middleware
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secrethaibc',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  // cookie: {secure: true}  //if using https only
  cookie: {maxAge: 5*60*60*1000 },               //5 hours of inactivity
  rolling: true
}));

//Passport Middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//method-override Middleware
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

//Set Global vars
app.use((req,res,next) => {
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  next();
});

//Use routes
app.use('/',index);
app.use('/auth',auth);
app.use('/stories',stories);

const port = process.env.PORT || 9000; //process.env.PORT for production port


app.listen(port,()=>console.log(`Server set at ${port}`));
```

passport.js

```
const FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const keys = require('./keys');

//Load User model
const User = mongoose.model('users');

module.exports = function(passport){

//FacebookStrategy
  passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: keys.facebookAppID,
    clientSecret: keys.facebookAppSecret,
    callbackURL: '/auth/facebook/callback',
    profileFields: ['id','displayName','photos','emails'], //did long method could have used 'name'
    proxy: true   //not sure about this
  }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done)=>{
    // console.log(accessToken);
    // console.log(profile);
   const image = `https://graph.facebook.com/${profile.id}/picture?`;
  //  console.log(image);
  const name = profile.displayName.split(' ');

  const newUser ={
    ID: profile.id,
    firstName: name[0],
    lastName: name[1],
    // firstName: profile.displayName.value.substring(0, profile.displayName.value.indexOf(' ')),
    // lastName: profile.displayName.value.substring(profile.displayName.value.indexOf(' '+ 1),),
    email: profile.emails[0].value,
    image: image
  }
  // console.log(newUser);    for debugging
  //Check for existing user
  User.findOne({
    ID: profile.id
  })
  .then(user => {
    if(user){
      //Return User
      done(null,user);
    }
    else{
      //Create User
      new User(newUser)
        .save()
        .then(user => done(null,user));
    }
  })

  })
 );

 //Serialize and Deserialize User
 passport.serializeUser((user,done)=>{
   done(null,user.id);
 });

 passport.deserializeUser((id,done)=>{
   User.findById(id, (err,user)=>{
     done(err,user);
   });
 });

}
```

auth.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');

//Google Authentication
router.get('/google',
  passport.authenticate('google',{scope: ['profile','email'] }));

router.get('/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google',{ failureRedirect: '/'}),(req,res)=>{
  // Successful authentication, redirect home.
  res.redirect('/dashboard')
});

//Facebook Authentication
router.get('/facebook',
  passport.authenticate('facebook'));

router.get('/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook',{failureRedirect:'/'}),(req,res)=>{
  // Successful authentication, redirect home.
  res.redirect('/dashboard');
});

router.get('/verify',(req,res)=>{
  if(req.user){
    console.log(req.user);
  } else {
    console.log('!!!!!!!! Not Auth !!!!!!!!!');
  }
});

router.get('/logout',(req,res)=>{
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});

module.exports = router;
```

[image]

If you want to try login: [App URL](https://ancient-spire-89530.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: Do you really expect us to troubleshoot without any code? Share the server code.

Comment: Please check once

Comment: This question is too broad. Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve